# Lettered Bus Numbers

Tags: word-choice, words

Consider the following categories of bus numbers:

- Number only - 11
- Number suffixed or prefixed with a character - 11E or E11
- Character only - A

**(Question)** How common are buses with letters/characters in Japanese? Do letters come before or after the number? Can the characters be English letters or hiragana/katakana/kanji?

---

I am familiar with `_番のバス` where the blank is for the number of the bus.

**(Question)** How frozen is `番のバス`? What happens if the blank is not a number. Do I change 番 if it is not a number and say `A字のバス`? What about the combination cases for bus 11E or E11?

Comment: If I were told 3番のバス, I would go to boarding location no. 3 rather than look for line no. 3. Are you sure you did not mean 号?

Comment: @macraf I did not learn about 号 being used with buses, so I don't know about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(Question 1)**

Buses in metropolitan areas are commonly (usually?) marked with numbers and letters. I don't know the statistical figure, but most buses have one number, possibly combined with one kanji or alphabet, followed by the destinations (eg. `茶51   秋葉原駅前`, `②つくばセンター`). Buses in rural areas may only have their destinations (eg. `湯涌温泉(行)`).

**(Question 2)**

番 can only follow a number. `2番のバス` is OK but `2のバス` sounds a bit weird. `A番のバス` is wrong and `Aのバス`/`Aと書かれたバス` is correct. `A字のバス` is uncommon and sounds like "A-shaped bus" to me. `E11番のバス` is acceptable but `E11のバス` is better.

Note that `2番のバス` may either mean a bus marked with 2 on the destination sign, or a bus coming to / departing from the platform number 2. It depends on the situation.